# Detect pauses in a digital signal on a scope?

Tags: oscilloscope, digital-communications

I am currently using a USB-SPI converter and I would like to know if there are stutters caused by some buffer starvation or anything else, i.e. pauses in the stream of digital data.

Is there a trick of some kind to detect such pauses using a generic digital scope? Ideally I'd like to trigger when there has not been an edge in the control channel after a certain timeout. After all the holdoff exists and I find that both are two sides of the same coin.

Obviously I can increase the time base, single-shoot, then zoom in and scroll, but this is very inconvenient if the stutters are rare and short.

I can provide a part number but I would prefer (out of curiosity) if there could be a solution that works with any basic digital scope.

Comment: I used some scopes that can trigger when a signal is higher/lower than a certain level for a time longer or shorter then some set time. I don't think we can speak here about "any basic digital scope"

Comment: A USB3 logic analyzer works really well here, since you can stream data over the bus and record the entire transaction even if its seconds or minutes long.  Some of the cheaper ones can do 1 GHz sampling or even run off an external clock if you want to sample synchronously with your device clock.

Answer (score 2):

If the USB data is going/coming from a computer, you can use Wireshark to monitor USB traffic. You can look at the timing of the packets in list and graphical formats. [Setup instructions](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) are on Wireshark's site.

Comment: I was more looking for something generic and electronics-based in this question but this is interesting for my initial problem, thanks. I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

Higher-end scopes have "compliance test modes" where you can specify that some regions of the signal after a trigger must be free or contain a signal transition. That works for your use case. But these are typical options for scopes in the higher-priced regions, not something I'd expect in a device that you can find no better description than "generic digital scope" for ;)

One way that probably works OK is

1. generate a sine wave of exactly the same frequency than your serial clock
2. connect that sine signal to your scopes main channel
3. connect the serial clock to the input you select as trigger
4. enable a lot of (digital) phosphor

If everything is well, the sine wave should always overlay in more or less the same exact position, only varying by the serial clock's jitter and the sine wave's phase noise.

The main problem here would generating the sine wave that has exactly the same frequency as your serial data. But: depending on the speed of your clock, a simple PLL IC (like even the olde 74HC4046) that you set (e.g. by removing a jumper to change the resistance in the RC loop filter) to a very narrow bandwidth once it's locked.

As a matter of fact, using a  PLL IC with a narrow loop filter is an interesting approach: With little external component effort, you can get (again, for example from the [74HCT4046](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd54hc4046a.pdf?ts=1649880432994&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)) a signal indicating "lock" on the signal phase. That's great! Just trigger your oscilloscope on the edges of that, and look what happened shortly before.

Comment: Interesting! This is the kind of hacks I was looking for. I'll keep the question open some more and will accept this answer by default. Thanks